# Advertised bandwidth rising but consensus weight falling?

Tags: relays, guard-node, bandwidth, raspberry-pi, consensus

I am a new non-exit relay operator, currently running TOR v4.5.4 rc on a RaspberryPi 3B+, on a FTTH connection.
My relay is https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#details/D4CB53B314610E6EBA3E583A861BE7B64402057C

As you can see, the relay is quite new but nevertheless old enough to have the Guard badge.
So I have successfully passed the phases 1 and 2 of this : https://blog.torproject.org/lifecycle-new-relay

My relay should now be used more and more. Both "Advertised bandwidth" and "Consensus weight" (meaning bandwidth measured by "Authorities bandwidth" if I have well understood) should be rising, at least they should be evolving in the same way.

However :

1/ My "RelayBandwidthRate" is set at 25MB/s in my torrc file and the "Advertised bandwidth" is only 5.71MB/s so the network is only seeing ~1/5 of my capacity.
I guess that I just have to wait but still, that is frustrating.

2/ Even weirder, the bandwidth graph and the consensus weight/guard probability/middle probability graph are moving in opposite directions !
I really don't understand what is happening here.
My logs are not showing any warnings.
These two graphs were approximately correlated at the beginning but now, they are doing non-sense for me.

Can you help me understand ?
Should I do something differently ?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: A bandwidth of 5.71MB/s is about the limit that the 3B+ CPU can handle. And even with a powerful enough computer, relays typically don't reach their max bandwidth rate.

Comment: The average use of the four CPU cores is only 30-35% and I have no messages in the logs regarding CPU throtlling.
You might be right anyway but, so far, I don't have the feeling that CPU is the issue.

Comment: The observed bandwidth is the maximum over a 10 second period in the past day, so try logging your cpu usage every few seconds and look at the max over a day. Also tor doesn't log any messages about high CPU load.